# How to explain in Numpy indexing an array with a list?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I've been trying to use Python lists as part of indices into Numpy arrays, and I'm seeing behavior that I don't understand.

The first example:

```
>>> a=np.zeros((5,5))
>>> a[0,[2,4]]=1
>>> a
array([[0., 0., 1., 0., 1.]
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

The second example:

```
>>> a=np.zeros((5,5))
>>> a[[1,3],[2,4]]=1
>>> a
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.]
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.]
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

In the first example `a[0,[2,4]]`, the first index is a scalar 0, the second a list.
It appears to me that the first index is treated as a specification of row, the second as column, and the first gets broadcast over the second to yield two row/column addresses `[0,2]` and `[0,4]`.

In the second example `a[[1,3],[2,4]]`, the first index is a list of rows, the second index is a list of columns, and they appear to be combined (broadcast?) to yield two row/column addresses `[1,2]` and `[3,4]`.

Can someone help me better understand how Numpy array addressing works?  I'm not sure what to Google for.

Comment: I googled "numpy indexing" and got the documentation: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html. This explains all sorts of array indexing, including "advanced indexing", which is what your code uses.

Comment: Yes they do broadcast.  Compare that with `np.arrat([1,3])+np.array([2,4])` which is [1+2, 3+4].

Comment: To test your `broadcasting` intuition, try `a[[[1],[3]],[2,4]]=1`.  or `a[np.ix_([1,3],[2,4])]`